# Using Webpack custom loader in loaders array

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to build a Webpack custom loader:

```
module.exports = function(source) {
  // Transform the source and return it
  console.log('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$');
  return source;

};
```

Now, I want to use it in my loaders array, something like:

```
loaders: [
      {test: /\.vm$/, loader: 'vm-loader', exclude: [/node_modules/, /dist/]}
]
```

I tried to use `resolveLoader`'s `alias`, but it did not work:

```
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
      "vm-loader": path.join(__dirname, "./lib/velocity-plugin")
    },
    root: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ]
  }
```

What Am I missing?

Comment: Where is this module exported in your codebase. Also, do you have an example of loading a .vm file in your code?

Comment: @SeanLarkin The export is inside "./lib/velocity-plugin". No example for now ):

Comment: _did not work_ means no `$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$` in console? Without any errors? And `velocity-plugin` is a file or it `"./lib/velocity-plugin/index.js"`?

Comment: @BobSponge no console, no errors. The velocity-plugin is the actual js file

Comment: Content of `.vm` files in bundle.js is empty or just raw file?

Comment: @BobSponge hmmm, wait. I don't see the vm files inside bundle.js, which is ok for me (don't want it inside bundle.js)

Comment: Does you importing `.vm` files anywhere in your code?

Comment: @BobSponge no, I don't

Comment: Ok, your code works fine. And it will better to move loader to `/lib/velocity-plugin/index.js` file.

Comment: @BobSponge so why is the vm not loaded? This is a file loaded by server, so no importing for it

Comment: `.vm` not loaded via webpack because you not importing it. How server loading this files?

Comment: @BobSponge so I must use some kind of a hackie solution?

Comment: Not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: @BobSponge ok, fair enough.. I guess that I'll find a solution when I will look for a solution for watching those html/vm files

Comment: @BobSponge FYI - the solution is something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33995496/916450

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

As it turned out, my custom loader doesn't work because webpack does not work on files which where not required. In my case those html/vm files are not required and not part of the bundle (they are rendered by the server).

My solution was adding gulp in order to have this working. Another (hacky) solution will be using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183931/how-to-watch-index-html-using-webpack-dev-server-and-html-webpack-plugin/33995496#33995496)