# Can I Hot-Serve index.html With webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the webpack-dev-server with `--hot` enabled, and it works great ... for Javascript files.  If I:

- create `/src/someFile.js` with the code `document.write("Foo");`
- add a `<script>` referencing `/src/someFile.js` to my `index.html`
- change `/src/someFile.js` to `document.write("Bar");`
- my browser immediately updates to show "Bar" instead of "Foo"

However, if I have `<p>Foo</p>` on my `index.html` file, and change it to `<p>Bar</p>`, I don't see the change.  If I refresh the page I do see the change though, so I know webpack is serving `index.html`; it's just not hot-swapping it when I save the file.

Does anyone know how I can fix `webpack-dev-server` to automatically update my HTML in response to file changes?

Comment: Two quick ideas to try. Point to `index.html` through an entry. You might need to set up a noop-loader against html. The point is that after that it's visible to webpack -> HMR should work. Another option would be to try [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) and generate index.html through it. You would handle modifications through its templating setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm afraid I'm somewhat new to Webpack, so I'm not exactly sure how to do all that.  I changed my `entry` to be an array of my `index.htm` and `app.js`, but then webpack complains about the loader.  And really I don't want an HTML loader, since my app has no need to load HTML as JS; I just want the (static, unprocessed) HTML file to hot-reload.

Comment: Yeah. It would have to be a part of the entry array, not the primary entry itself. And even then you would have to pass html through a noop loader to avoid that error you mentioned. html-webpack-plugin could be a better option. Third option would be to have `require.context` pointing to index.html somewhere. The main thing is that you point to the file somehow as otherwise it won't be watched.

Answer (score 7):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33995496/476228) should work like a charm for you. In your example the steps are:

1. `npm install --save-dev raw-loader`
2. Add this to your webpack.config loaders section...

   ```
   {
     test: /\.html$/,
     loader: "raw-loader"
   }
   ```
3. Add a `require('index.html');` line to the top of `/src/someFile.js`.

Basically you're just making webpack aware of index.html so that it watches for changes. This is just a quick fix for your particular problem but for anyone interested in the more in-depth 'why' of this solution refer to the more thorough explanation linked above.