# Webpack Dev Server include additional files for watching

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am working on a server side renderer for `Vue` and I am using the `webpack dev server` as a development server. It already works quite well, I have setup the server so that it triggers a build when one of the source files get changed. Of course it does that out of the box because my source files are part of the `entry` in the `webpack` config.

Now with `Vue` you can also point to a `html` file that serves as a template for server side rendering. It is fairly simple to pass that html file to Vue for doing server side rendering.

Now what I want to do is update the `Vue` server side renderer every time the `html` file changes. So basically all I need to to is tell `webpack` or the `webpack dev server` respectively to also watch for file changes on that `html` file.

How can I do that?

For context, this is the gist of my `webpack` config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    client: 'src/path/to/client.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: appDist,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.vue', '.js', '.json', '.mjs'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [/* ...*/],
  },
  /* some other options here */
  devServer: {
    contentBase: [appDist, appPublic],
    publicPath: '/',
    port: 8080,
    compress: false,
    overlay: true,
    quiet: true,
  }
};
```

Now I also want to tell webpack to also trigger a rebuild when

```
'public/index.html'
```

changes.

Note that I am calling webpack and the dev server manually like so

```
const compiler = webpack([config.client, config.server]);
const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, config.devServer);
```

So I also have all the options that I have with `JavaScript` it it's not possible to do this via configuration

Comment: import that index.html on src/path/to/client.js.

Comment: I don't know much about Vue but check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183931/how-to-watch-index-html-using-webpack-dev-server-and-html-webpack-plugin