# Modify NODE_ENV accordingly

Tags: node.js, express, docker

I'm rewriting a project from scratch using best practices and better config variables.
The idea is to have at least 3 environments:

- **development** = hosted locally (on machine)
- **acceptance** = hosted on personal NAS
- **production** = hosted on rented server

After some research I came across the following answer (on how to set NODE_ENV): [9198310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x)

Doesn't this mean I have to change the environment manually before each code push? Is there a way to do this automatically by checking IP or DNS?

FYI, I'm using docker to host the website on acceptance & production. Not locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can export **NODE_ENV** for each environment (can be added on profile.d on OS level) and then just start your nodejs app which will read that env. variable.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app"
  }
```

When run docker, you can set env. variable using:

```
 -e NODE_ENV='staging
```

Also you can take a look at pm2 manager.