# How does node/react determine if my app is in production?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, web-deployment

I was told to put the following code in my package.json to make my react/node app run faster:

```
  "babel": {
    "env": {
      "production": {
        "plugins": [
          "transform-react-constant-elements",
          "transform-react-inline-elements"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Similarly I have some dependencies that are supposedly for developement:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.17.0",
    "eslint": "^3.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
```

This being my first time deploying a live site (on AWS), I was wondering how the software I'm using knows whether the app is in production mode or in developement?  If this question leads you to believe I may be ignorant with regard to other things necessary to optimally deploy a site, please fill me in, thank you.

Comment: you usually have a configuration that defines that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the environment variable to "production", many services you deploy on do that by default.

Comment: Which environment variable?

Comment: @5ar yes can you please clarify which one

Comment: the node environment, the syntax depends which OS you are using but it goes something like `NODE_ENV=production`, for a few examples check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // some code here
}
```

Comment: might be worth adding some more info about what `process.env.NODE_ENV` is for those unfamiliar.