# How does nodejs read environment variables set in command line?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, environment-variables

I feel like asking a silly question but I have googled it for a while and can't find a satisfying answer. SO doesn't such discussion either, only [How to set NODE_ENV to production/development in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x) and [How can I set NODE_ENV=production on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows)

To run a command after another in one line we normally join them by `;` ( or `&&`)

So I had assumed I should run command like this `PORT=3000 ; node server.js` or `export PORT=3000; node server.js` , just like `PORT=3000 ; echo $PORT`

But we just put **a space** between `PORT=3000 node server.js` (without `;` or `&&`) and PORT is read into `process.env.PORT.` How does shell make nodejs get environment variables? It will be better if someone can show nodejs codes.

----- update ------

The reason I was puzzled with this shell syntax (according to my limited knowledge) is that I think the general format for a Unix command line is

```
command options(s) filename(s)
```

The space in between is used to separate command from option and filename. So how can it be used to separate 2 commands as well?

Comment: Why do you think that it is only available in node?? Do `PORT=3000 echo Qiulang`

Comment: I assume you were trying to help but my understanding is that putting a space between two commands just does not work. And that is my question.

Comment: I am saying it is not Nodejs specific so u won't get any Nodejs code. Not sure, but it is part of shell syntax

Comment: @Qiulang dude, i think it *is* valid syntax, you can try with `PORT=1000 echo 'hello' && echo 'world'`, if first half failed everything after && won't get executed.

Comment: @Xlee I will suggest to you try  PORT=1000 echo $PORT and you can see the result is empty. i.e. PORT is not set

Comment: @Qiulang wants to  leave as comment but not easy to format, see below

Comment: @bugwheels94 see my updated question.

Comment: can you drop a reference for your so said  "general format for a unix command", i am not sure if `pwd echo type` etc fits this format.

Comment: @Xlee oh sorry that is just my understanding, no reference.

Comment: i guess you might be interested in this: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: Thanks for the link but did you see the words "A command list embedded between parentheses runs as a subshell." That is exactly what I was trying to say. You got to have some way to separate 2 commands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164946/discussion-between-xlee-and-qiulang).

Answer (score 1):

I checked nodejs document and found the answer https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

So it is [environ](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), not 2 separated commands,

> Bourne-style shells support the syntax
>
> ```
>        NAME=value command
> ```
>
> to create an environment variable definition only in the scope of the
>   process that executes command.

Or as [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf) 3.7.4 explained.

[For python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values), it is `os.environ['NAME']`

This is also the reason why it won't work on windows: [How can I set NODE_ENV=production on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows)

Notes for Windows users, as a comment there by daw "set NODE_ENV=production && " adds a trailing space to the variable and don't use single/double quote.

I feel quite embarrassed that I almost wanted to delete my question. I keep it here in case someone else may also have this doubt. Or someone else can further explain **environ** or how node read it into process.env object.