# How to properly assign development vs production variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I don't know how to ask this question, so I will describe what I'm doing, and I'd like some enlightenment.

I'm using `node` with `express` for server-side rendering.

When I'm developing the web app, there's a module holding a variable which is shared across all the express routes, instead of hard-coding it.

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    ipAddress: "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

**index.js** route

```
var config = require("../../config.js");

router
    .get('/', function (req, res) {
        var html = `
            <div class="content">
                <a href="${config.ipAddress}/orders">Orders</a>
                <a href="${config.ipAddress}/invoices">Invoices</a>
            </div>
        `
        res.send(html);
    });

module.exports = router;
```

When it's time to deploy the app, I **manually** change the `config.js` into the server's IP address:

```
module.exports = {
    ipAddress: "http://255.255.255.255"
}
```

Another example is the `scripts.js` file referenced in the HTML head, which handles the `DOM` changes. Again, the server IP address is placed in the variable.

**scripts.js**

```
var ipAddress = "http://localhost:8080"; // To be changed into "http://255.255.255.255"

function placeOrder() {
    fetch(`${ipAddress}/place-order`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        }
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => xonsole.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

document.getElementById("submit-order").addEventListener("click", () => placeOrder());
```

**What is a proper way to handle these variable changes automatically?**

Comment: Use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason for fully qualifying the reference? If your directory structure is the same you could just use relative referencing, for example change '${ipAddress}/place-order' into '/place-order'

Answer (score 3):

One proper way would be to use the processes environment. For example you could switch based on `NODE_ENV`:

```
 const ipAdress = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "http://255.255.255" : "http://localhost";
```

For sure you could also take a custom variable

```
const ipAddress = process.env.ORDER_SERVER;
```

[These variables can then be set to different values on different servers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204973/5260024)

---

To pass the changes to *clientside javascript* you need to write them into the files delivered to the client somewhere on the server. That could be done easily with templates, e.g. ejs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How about the second part i.e. `scripts.js` served in the HTML head? Would this work too for a file not part of Node?

Comment: @babevski you have to write it to the clientside files.

Comment: I apologize for not marking your answer as correct. You answered my question correctly, but the other one showed me that it wasn't needed in the first place.

Comment: @babevski yes, in this case the other answer is definetly the better solution... You didn't know about relative URLs? °_°

Comment: Yeah, I am very ashamed... I have no idea how I've never realized it.