# nestJs handle env variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, dotenv

I would configure enivrement variables in nestjs as mentioned in documentation [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration):

in my service constructor I get env file path

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export class ConfigService {
  private readonly envConfig: { [key: string]: string };

  constructor(filePath: string) {
    this.envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath))
    console.log(this.envConfig)
  }

  get(key: string): string {
    return this.envConfig[key];
  }
}
```

Then in config module I set the config service

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useValue: new ConfigService(`${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`),
    },
  ],
  exports: [ConfigService],
})
```

**Current behavior**

Actually I get process.env.NODE_ENV value undefined

**Expected behavior**

get env variable path in process.env.NODE_ENV

Comment: Provide `filePath` value what you want. Example it is `my_test.env`, then you have to set your `NODE_ENV` to `my_test`, we have too many way to set `NODE_ENV` environment variable value, a simple way `NODE_ENV=my_test npm run start`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining Node environment in Nest.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092953/defining-node-environment-in-nest-js)

Comment: Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364907/4694994

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issue. Easy fixed it by manually importing dotenv in file `main.ts`, just like in the example below (please make sure you've installed `dotenv`):

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();
// all rest of your code
```

Hope it might help!