# How to apply google analytics code for local and production

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-analytics

I would like to know how to apply google analytics id for local and production,

I have two `ID`'s, each for local and production.
I am using `node.js` as a backend, and stored the google analytics key in config file using `env` file.

How to pass:

- If local, pass google analytics id `ga_local`;
- If prod, pass google analytics id `ga_pro` in `node.js` in the startup.

**.env**

```
ga_local = "UA-XXXX-X",
ga_pro = "UA-YYYY-Y"
```

**config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const config = {
    ga_local: process.env.ga_local,
    ga_pro: process.env.ga_pro
};
module.exports = config;
```

**front end**

```
<script async src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${ga_local}'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `process.env. NODE_ENV` variable and set it while starting the server for development or production accordingly. Refer this: [How to set NODE_ENV to production/development in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x/35040401)

Comment: thanks for reply, is it like this `"start": "set NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev node app.js"` in package.json?

Comment: Yeah. You got it right. And using `process.env.NODE_ENV` to access the value like `ga_id = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? ga_local : ga_pro;`

Comment: @Senthil Don't use `set` here, instead try `"start": "export NODE_ENV=production && node app.js"`

Comment: this means always set to production right, then how do i set code