# process.env.NODE_ENV === "developement" even in production

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I want to deploy a React app (made with Create React App) + a Node server with Heroku,

I did it, but my app can't fetch data from the server,

In production, my process.env.NODE_ENV is equal to "development" which causes a lot of wrong stuff in my code,

Do you know what can put process.env.NODE_ENV always at "development"? At the build, this environment variable is supposed to switch to "production", no?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file?

Comment: hi, you can watch it here : https://github.com/Versifiction/ofilms/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set NODE\_ENV to production/development in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

Your `package.json` add this.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=development; {your start code}",
```

Answer (score 0):

Your env variables can be set per *environment*, in this case in Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard

If you want to make sure `build` always runs with the same `NODE_ENV`, you can follow @seunggabi 's answer. I'd also use `cross-env` to make it work cross-platform in such case. Per-process variable can be forced on `heroku-postbuild` task (after `&&`).

Comment: hi, I also have the script heroku postbuild in my package json ("heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"), but it looks like the build is not done because my node_env variable is still at development...

Comment: My suggestion was to try `heroku-postbuild` as `npm install && cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run build` (after adding `cross-env` to dev-dependencies)

Answer (score -1):

You can take control of your Environment with [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd). They make easy to switch between your local development, testing, staging, UAT or production.

You can refer to this [article](https://dev.to/jam3/managing-env-variables-for-provisional-builds-h37). This is was very helpful for me

Comment: thank you for the resource, I read the article, but if I'm not wrong, I still don't understand why my process.env.NODE_ENV is at "development" in production :'(

Comment: @Versifiction you tried `npm run build` or command that creates optimized production bundle?

Comment: yes the script is done every time I deploy but the env variable it still at development, but don't worry I did it with another solution

Comment: Please summarize the main points of the article to avoid a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).