# can't run npm install in laravel project how to fix it

Tags: reactjs, laravel, npm-install

I'm creating a laravel application with react template, when I run npm install 
 throws an error exception, I also tried changing folder permissions, removed 
`node_modules` then reinstalled it but not working any solutions???

[image: error]

Comment: it says that the package : libpng-dev is missing .. install it before runing npm install

Comment: "removed node_modules then reinstall it but working"; Is it working or not?

Comment: sorry typo missing ,not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the error I see in your console:

> pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed

Seems like you don't have a `pngquant` package installed. Try the following steps:

Install package locally:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

Install npm package:

```
npm install -g pngquant-bin
```

If you already have node_modules directory in your project, delete it and install node_modules again:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Image Provided, Everything seems to be fine until it hits this missing package causing the exception to be thrown.

The missing package is **libpng-dev**: A virtual package.

See the [Debian policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) for a definition of virtual packages.
You can see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng-dev) for details.

---

You have to Run this Command

`sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`

In case you hit an error saying it has been installed before, It means you have installed another build of this package. Hence, you have to reinstall it.

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpng12-0=1.2.51-0ubuntu3`

And then, try running `npm install`

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue in my localhost environment by moving libraries from `devDependencies{}` into `dependencies{}`

**Otherwise**

You should set global Node environment called `NODE_ENV` to `development`

> NODE_ENV=development

**References**

[How to set NODE_ENV to production/development in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x/35040401)

[Environment variables in Node.js. The Right way!](https://dev.to/numtostr/environment-variables-in-node-js-the-right-way-15ad)